# Does the git clean command run any hooks?

Tags: git, githooks

I have run `git clean -dfix` in the working copy of an untrusted codebase, and I am wondering if any git hooks might have been invoked.

The [git clean docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean) don't mention hooks at all and the [hooks docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks) don't mention the `clean` command, but I am left uncertain.

Comment: What is the source of your uncertaintly? The [`githooks` man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks) documents all of the hooks that git knows about. If it's not there, it doesn't exist.